# Which should I follow?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, gridview, dataset

I've used Status of subject (e.g. active, inactive, booked etc...) and I'm maintaining short form of them.

But During my programming, I need to display their full name in grid view.

Which step I should follow and WHY?

1) Add another column at run time containing full form.
2) Apply condition every time to check status and apply its value to control.
3)any other?

Comment: What do you mean by "short form of them"?  How does "short form" differ from "full form"?

Comment: for ex. if status is `Active`, i'm using `AC` in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should make a table where you define short form in a column and  Full name in another column

When you fetch data in full name then you get by this table with respect short form

You can Put join ,if you are using another table

```
id  shortform   fullname
1   act         Active
2   ina        Inactive
3   boo         Booked

select *,s.fullname from tableanother t join shorttable s on s.shortform = t.id
```

And Another Way You can use Flag 
as
a

Active 1
Inactive 2
booked 3

I hope it will  helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

You have a column with short form, lets pretend: "act", "ina", "bkd" etc.

You want to show "Subject active", "Subject inactive", "Already Booked" etc.

As you say you could simply add a column with those values, but that would waste space, you'd have a copy of "Subject active" in every record with that status, and similarly for all other records.

Having the logic in your presentation layer might be good, some simple lookup table in your UI. For example a drop down list often has that capability. This could be useful if you need to support multiple languages. You surely don't want an English column and a French column and a German column in your DB.

Another possibility is to have a reference table

```
  act | Subject Active
  ina | Subject Inactive
  bkd | Already Booked
```

Now your query just does a join to retrieve the textual value. In this case you could have different columns for each language without undue duplication.

Comment: Ok, this illustration is understandable. But in creating reference table wouldn't increase server side trip?

Comment: No, you do a single query using a JOIN. Database are very good at that sort of thing, I'm not going to write a SQL tutorial here, go read about how to do a single query retrieving data from multiple tables.